# Prove or disprove for any real number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove for any real number $x^2 < x$ , considering $0.5^2 = 0.25, 0.25 < 0.5$

Comment: What happens when x = 2??

Comment: then x^2 = 4, but what about decimal numbers?

Comment: Are decimal numbers not considered real numbers in Discrete Math?

Comment: That's the issue: the proposition says "_any_ real number".  Does the inequality _always_ hold?  If not, how should the proposition be re-written?

Comment: For bonus marks, can you give a quick description of all the reals $x$ for which $x^2\lt x$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, LOL!! that's about how long its taking me to finish this homework...smh

Comment: @André Nicolas: If I may claim that I would say $x \in (0, 1)$

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, not sure. "any integer"?

Comment: @Ishfaaq: Precisely!

Comment: As a proposition which could be proven _true_ for the given inequality, one might write, for instance, "Prove that $ \ x^2  <  x \ $ for $ \ 0 < x < 1 \  $ " .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, nice, that makes much more sense than my useless textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you are asked to prove is "For any real number $x, \;\; x^2 \lt x$". Note the statement quantifies the claim *for all*  real numbers. It is wrong if it does not work for at least one. So to disprove all you need is to provide one counter-example such as $2$. The fact that it works for other real numbers is irrelevant.

Comment: oooohhhhh. thank you so much! I was overthinking it.

Comment: @Solomon: Anytime..

Comment: That's the wonderful thing about mathematical propositions (and physical theories): you can knock 'em down with just one counter-example.  _Proofs_ that some statement is _always_ true, on the other hand, can sometimes be **very** difficult...

Comment: I'm learning more here than in college. sad.

Comment: @Solomon: I hear ya!!

Comment: Since this is a _proper_ inequality, one could even disprove the original proposition with 0 or 1 .